# Keeps getting dependency problems when I try to install new packages

Tags: python, dependencies

I have been trying to install some software packages for hours now but I keep getting errors to do with python3.

When running apt-get -f install this is the output, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lsb-release:
 lsb-release depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package lsb-release (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-apt:
 python3-apt depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-apt depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-apt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-dbus:
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-dbus depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-dbus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-gi:
 python3-gi depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-gi depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-gi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-asn1crypto:
 python3-asn1crypto depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-asn1crypto (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-certifi:
 python3-certifi depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-certifi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-configargparse:
 python3-configargparse depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-configargparse (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-funcsigs:
 python3-funcsigs depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-funcsigs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-future:
 python3-future depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-future (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-icu:
 python3-icu depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-icu depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-icu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-idna:
 python3-idna depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-idna (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pkg-resources:
 python3-pkg-resources depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pkg-resources (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pyasn1:
 python3-pyasn1 depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pyasn1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pycurl:
 python3-pycurl depends on python3 (<< 3.6); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-pycurl depends on python3 (>= 3.5~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pycurl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-pyparsing:
 python3-pyparsing depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-pyparsing (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-six:
 python3-six depends on python3:any (>= 3.4~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-six (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-software-properties:
 python3-software-properties depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on python3-apt (>= 0.6.20ubuntu16); however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on python3-pycurl; however:
  Package python3-pycurl is not configured yet.
 python3-software-properties depends on lsb-release; however:
  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-software-properties (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of software-properties-common:
 software-properties-common depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.
 software-properties-common depends on python3-software-properties (= 0.96.20.9); however:
  Package python3-software-properties is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package software-properties-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-tz:
 python3-tz depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-tz (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unattended-upgrades:
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3-apt; however:
  Package python3-apt is not configured yet.
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3-gi; however:
  Package python3-gi is not configured yet.
 unattended-upgrades depends on python3-dbus; however:
  Package python3-dbus is not configured yet.
 unattended-upgrades depends on lsb-release; however:
  Package lsb-release is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package unattended-upgrades (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dh-python:
 dh-python depends on python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~); however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package dh-python (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 lsb-release
 python3-apt
 python3-dbus
 python3-gi
 python3-asn1crypto
 python3-certifi
 python3-configargparse
 python3-funcsigs
 python3-future
 python3-icu
 python3-idna
 python3-pkg-resources
 python3-pyasn1
 python3-pycurl
 python3-pyparsing
 python3-six
 python3-software-properties
 software-properties-common
 python3-tz
 unattended-upgrades
 dh-python
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```